# Can a web server set itself to sleep mode when there is no traffic on it?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, webserver

I have a strange problem. I use Sun One 6.1 web server and I put a jsp which contains only an image and a link to go itself.

When I visit the page using browser it works fine. Then if I click the link quickly it still works fine. However, if I click, lets say 10-15 seconds later, it is loaded after a long wait. The page load can take even 4-5 secs. Then it continues to work with 50-60msec load time.

Is it normal ? If my server has a little traffic this issue will be gone ?

Comment: I have upticked this question, but also voted to close, because there could be any number of reasons that could be causing the behavior you are reporting, and there's no way for us to say for sure how to fix it or if its okay

Comment: I think the reason may be other activity on the server (machine). When your web server (software) is unused, and other software needs memory, your web server may be swapped out. The 4-5 sec delay is the time it takes to read it back into memory. Similarly, if the server (OS) is a VM, the host machine may need the memory for other VM's, and cause similar swap-out.

Comment: This is why I describe this as "a strange problem". I asked this, hoping maybe someone can tell me where should I suspect. Operating System, application server, jdk version, even the hdd.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the suggestion. I got a dedicated server. RAM and CPU values are quite normal. Machine has 32GB RAM and my jsp is trying to show an only 10kb image. There is no any other activity on the server yet.